# VueJs + Vuex + mapActions

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

In the documentation, it is written that the state is immutable apart from the mutations called via the actions ... Ok.

I use in my component, mapGetters, mapActions ...

store :

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    color: "violet"
  },
  mutations: {
      changeColor(state, newColor) {
          state.color = newColor
      },
  },
  actions: {
    changeColor({ commit }, newColor) {
      commit('changeColor', newColor)
  }
 }
```

component :

```
...
methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      setColor: 'store/changeColor',
    }),
    myMethodCallByButton(){
       this.setColor("blue").then(response => {
          console.log("change Color done")
       },err => {
          console.log("change Color error")
       })
    }
...
```

The method works fine, the store is updated, EXCEPT that I never receive the console.log ().

It is written in the documentation that mapActions were equivalent to this.$store.dispatch.

- Why do not I get the message?
- Is there another solution ?

PS: I want to keep the mapGetters map, mapActions .. I do not like calling this.$store.dispatch

PS2: I work with modules in my store

Thank you

Comment: It works for me (the console log prints): https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/s7k3fxsn/

Comment: I've write a short code, so the execution is real quick but if you add a setTimeout for simulate a big operation, there is a problem.

Comment: I think possibly the problem is about handling the promise, then... Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/s7k3fxsn/16/ see if it makes it clearer

Comment: Okay so that means that even if the mapAction / dispatch returns a promised, I am in my case obliged to add a promise to wait for the end of the "mutation". I thought, from the documentation, that it was precisely managed via the mapAction. Is it exact ?

Comment: I tried to address that in the answer. Check it out, please.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every Vuex **action returns a `Promise`**.

Vuex [wraps the results of the action functions into `Promise`s](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/86677ebcbfaecf712f339b73a568150fc9fd5f5e/src/store.js#L133-L135). So the `changeColor` action in:

```js
actions: {
  changeColor({ commit }, newColor) {
    myAsyncCommand();
  }
}
```

Returns a `Promise` that resolves to `undefined` and that **will not wait for** the completion `myAsyncCommand();`'s asynchronous code (if it doesn't contain async code, then there's no waiting to do).

This happens because the code above is the same as:

```js
  changeColor({ commit }, newColor) {
    myAsyncCommand();
    return undefined;
  }
```

And when `.dispatch('changeColor', ...)` Vuex will then return `Promise.resolve(undefined)`.

If you want the `Promise` returned by the action to wait, you should return a `Promise` that does the property waiting yourself. Something along the lines of:

```js
  changeColor({ commit }, newColor) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      myAsyncCommand().then(resolve);
    });
    // or, simply: return myAsyncCommand();
  }
```

Demo implementation below with more details:

```js
const myStore = {
  namespaced: true,
  state: { color: "violet" },
  mutations: {
      changeColor(state, newColor) {
          state.color = newColor
      }
  },
  actions: {
    changeColor_SIMPLE({ commit }, newColor) {
      commit('changeColor', newColor)
    },
    changeColor_COMPLICATED_NO_PROMISE({ commit }, newColor) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          commit('changeColor', newColor)
        }, 2000)
    },
    changeColor_COMPLICATED_WITH_PROMISE({ commit }, newColor) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          commit('changeColor', newColor)
          resolve();
        }, 2000)
      });
    }
  }
};
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    store: myStore,
  }
});
new Vue({
  store,
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapActions({
      setColorSimple: 'store/changeColor_SIMPLE',
      setColorComplicatedNoPromise: 'store/changeColor_COMPLICATED_NO_PROMISE',
      setColorComplicatedWithPromise: 'store/changeColor_COMPLICATED_WITH_PROMISE',
    }),
    myMethodCallByButton(){
       this.setColorSimple("blue")
        .then(response => console.log("SIMPLE done"),err => console.log("SIMPLE err"));
      this.setColorComplicatedNoPromise("blue")
        .then(response => console.log("NO_PROMISE done"),err => console.log("NO_PROMISE err"));
      this.setColorComplicatedWithPromise("blue")
        .then(response => console.log("WITH_PROMISE done"),err => console.log("WITH_PROMISE err"));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>color: {{ $store.state.store.color }}</p>
  <button @click="myMethodCallByButton">click me and WAIT for 2s</button>
</div>
```

#### Update/Per comments:

> Even if the mapAction / dispatch returns a promised, I am in my case obliged to add a promise to wait for the end of the "mutation". I thought, from the documentation, that it was precisely managed via the mapAction. Is it exact?

If an action calls a mutation only, such as:

```js
actions: {
  changeColor({ commit }, newColor) {
    commit('changeColor', newColor)
    return undefined; // added for clarity
  }
}
```

Then the returned `Promise` will only execute *after* the `commit()` completes.

That does not happen because Vuex manages waiting of mutations (`commit`s).

It happens that way because there's no waiting to do. This is because Vuex requires: [**mutations must be synchronous operations**](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html#mutations-must-be-synchronous).

Since mutations are synchronous, the line of the `return` above will only execute after the code of the line before (`commit('changeColor', newColor)`).

**Note:** If your mutations have asynchronous code, you should make them synchronous, as it goes against how Vuex properly works and may yield all kinds of unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect

Comment: in case I call a "mapGetters" and it takes time to return the data there is a problem. Let's say that I loop with a "v-for" by calling a "getAll" method that calls "mapGetters / getall". there is absolutely nothing happening in the DOM

Comment: By `mapGetters` you mean like `methods: {
    ...Vuex.mapGeters({`?

Comment: Absolutely. in my template : `<div v-for="a in M"...></div>.`  In my methods, `M() {  return ...mapGetters("getAll(data)") }`.   in store, getter: { getAll:state... }`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but `...mapGetters("getAll(data)")` doesn't seem right. Does it work? Because it seems it should be `...mapGetters(["getAll"])`

Comment: no mapGetters is ok (just example). The problem is : if getter take lot of time (as we seen with setTimeout), the dom no render with datas

Comment: You mean you have getter that is asynchronous? `setTimeout` is asynchronous.

Comment: We can say that. it take a lot of time before render (lot of data in my state). So it's as an asynchronous

Comment: They are not really the same thing... JavaScript has only one thread, if it is synchronous, even if it takes a looong time, it will hang the UI. (e.g. try a  `for(let i = 0; i < 99999999999999; i++)`). Asynchronous code returns right away, but "triggers" some computation that will be executed sometime later (like an ajax call, the response will come, you just don't know when). Getters should really have only synchronous code.

Comment: Yes i know. So i m obligate to call a mapAction who return to me values from state instead of mapGetter if il take long time ?

Comment: No... You should call an action to trigger the update. And use a getter in a computed. When the action updates the state, the computed will call the getter and update the UI automatically. This is the standard way of using Vue/Vuex.

Comment: Do you have an exemple please ? I don't see